# jQuery and template with jSON

Tags: php, jquery, templates, handlebars.js

I'm trying to use handlebars (templating) to organize a fetched jSon object through ajax

This is what the object looks like, **PHP:**

```
[0] => Url Object
    (
        [url_id] => 1
        [url] => www.stackoverflow.com
        [tags] => Array
            (
                [0] => Tag Object
                    (
                        [tag_id] => 1
                        [tag_name] => programming
                    )

                [1] => Tag Object
                    (
                        [tag_id] => 2
                        [tag_name] => questions
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Url Object
    (
        [url_id] => 2
        [url] => www.twitter.com
        [tags] => Array
            (
                [0] => Tag Object
                    (
                        [tag_id] => 3
                        [tag_name] => messaging
                    )

            )

    )
```

I'm able to obtain url_id and url from both Object[0] and object [1] through: **(JQUERY)**

```
$.getJSON(url,function(data){

                    Bookmarks = $.map(data,function(bookmark){ //segundo param = callback function

                                    return{
                                      url_id: bookmark.url_id,
                                      url: bookmark.url,
                                      tags: bookmark.tags
                                          }
                                                                  });

                var contenedor = $('#scriptmark').html();
                var template = Handlebars.compile(contenedor);
                var i = 0;
                while( i < Bookmarks.length){
                $('#sites').append(template(Bookmarks[i]));
                i++;}
        });
```

And finally, this is what my template looks like:

```
<script id="script" type="text/x-handlebars-template">


            <div class="site">
            Site: {{url}} Tags: {{tag}}
            </div>


</script>
```

**I'm trying to figure out how to get those tags, because when i do the tamplating i obviously get returned the Object**

Comment: Do you mean recover the tags from the div you create with the template? or get the tags data from the JSON variable you get using Ajax?

Comment: I need to get the fields inside the Tag object, i know i can get them saying for example Bookmarks.[i].tags[0].tag_name , but I cannot come up with an idea on how to fetch them all through my jquery loop (refer to Jquery part in question) thanks for reading

Comment: use a `helper` method that loops over `tags` and returns a string

Comment: if i knew how to i wouldnt be asking x.x

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this?

```
 Bookmarks = $.map(data,
     function(bookmark){ //segundo param = callback function
         var tagstring="";
         $.each(bookmark.tags, function(index, value){
              if(index > 0){tagstring+=", ";}
              tagstring+=value.tag_id+"-->"+value.tag_name;
         }
         return
         {
                url_id: bookmark.url_id,
                url: bookmark.url,
                tags: tagstring
         }
      }
 );
```